# How do I find cosine similarity between two text documents using Java?

Tags: java, nlp, tf-idf, cosine-similarity, doc2vec

I need to compare a large number of tweets containing a particular hashtag to display the tweet which has the highest content in it. For the same, I need to find pair-wise cosine similarity between each one of them and display the tweet with highest pair-wise cosine similarity as output. I've been reading a lot about vector space Models, tf-idf vectors, word2vec/doc2vec etc. but couldn't grasp anything completely. I need to implement the same using Java. Is there any alternative to scikit-learn's TfidfVectorizer or NLTK's synsets?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Mahout for vectorizing all text documents residing in a folder.

The first step is to create *sequence files* and then create *vectors* from these *sequence files*.

This [page](https://mahout.apache.org/users/basics/creating-vectors-from-text.html) describes how to do it. Then you can use the *RowSimilarityJob* class to compute the cosine similarities.